# Solving time-dependent differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth path defined on the open interval $I$. The initial value problem
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t)=a(t)x(t), x(t_0)=x_0$$
has a solution for all $t_0 \in I$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, namely
$$x(t)=x_0e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(s) \ ds}$$
because
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t)=x_0e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(s) \ ds} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{t_0}^t a(s) \ ds \right) = x(t)a(t)$$
and
$$x(t_0)=x_0 e^{\int_{t_0}^{t_0}a(s) \ ds}= x_0e^0=x_0.$$

Now instead suppose $A:I \to M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is smooth, and we wish to solve
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t)=A(t)x(t), x(t_0)=x_0.$$
[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems) there is no closed-form solution for a differential equation of this form. What goes wrong with defining
$$x(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s) \ ds}x_0$$
where now we use the matrix exponential? Is this not considered to be a closed-form solution?

Comment: No, this formula in general does not work. It will be only true if the matrix is such that $A(t)A(s)=A(s)A(t)$ for any $t$ and $s$, which is a very stringent requirement.

Comment: Why exactly is that required? Isn't
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t)= A(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\ ds}x_0=A(t)x(t)$$
and $x(t_0)=e^0x_0=x_0$?

Comment: No, this formula does not hold in general. See my hint below, just work through this example and you will see why your approach would not work.

Comment: Is the problem that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{M(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} M(t)^k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} kM(t)^{k-1} M'(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} M(t)^k M'(t)= e^{M(t)}M'(t)$$
and in general this is not equal to $M'(t)e^{M(t)}$?

Comment: The main problem, as I already indicated above, is in general noncommutativity of $A(s)A(t)$. In you computations you also assume that $((A(t))^k)'=kA(t)^{k-1}A'(t)$, which is also not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Take
$$
A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
1&t\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Find the solution directly. Calculate matrix exponential. Compare the results.

*Hint #2:* To see how commutativity plays the role, take your "solution" and try to differentiate, taking into account that
$$
(A(t)B(t))'=A'(t)B(t)+A(t)B'(t).
$$

Comment: Okay, for say $x_0=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $t_0=0$ I get $x(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ e^{t^2/2} \end{pmatrix}$, and the equation I wrote in my answer gives $x(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \frac{2}{t}\left(e^{t^2/2}-1\right) & e^{t^2/2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1  \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ e^{t^2/2} \end{pmatrix}$...

Comment: I integrated $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & s\end{pmatrix}$ from $0$ to $t$ to get $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ t & t^2/2 \end{pmatrix}$ and took its matrix exponential to get the matrix I wrote in the comment above.

Comment: Try another initial conditions :)

Comment: I'm having trouble solving it in any case when $x_1 \neq 0$ because then I get $x_2'(t)=x_1(t)+tx_2(t)$... I know $x_1(t)$ will be a constant $c=x_1(0)$, but I still don't know how to solve $x_2'(t)=c+tx_2(t)$.

Comment: I guess in any case my "solution" will give me $x(t)=\begin{pmatrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) e^{t^2/2} \end{pmatrix}$, which does not work...

Comment: I still don't see why this failure comes about because $A(t)A(s) \neq A(s)A(t)$, though.

Comment: @kccu The matrix exponent is usually motivated by Picard's iterates. Start the process with time dependent matrix and will see how commutativity plays the role.

Comment: Ah the "Hint 2" makes more sense to me. Thank you.